# How can I determine the length of data in bytes for the call to glTexImage3D()?

Tags: opengl, trace, opengl-4

I'm tracing some gl calls and want to record the data passed into glTexImage3D(). I need to know how many bytes long the data is.

It starts off easy with:

```
size_t num_pixels = width*height*depth;
```

But I'm not sure of the correct way to determine the bytes per pixel given `internalformat`, `format`, and `type`?

Does `format` give me the color components? and `type` give me the number of bits per color component?

Comment: e.g.  if the format is `GL_RGBA`, then there are 4 color channels (red, green, blue, alpha). If the type is `GL_BYTE`, then the size of 1 color channel is 1 byte. So the size of the image in bytes is `width*height*depth*4*1`. But the size depends on your image data. You have to set the "format" and the "type" parameter suiting to you image data.

Comment: and you also have to track the pixel unpack state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *internalformat* parameter is irrelevant for figuring out the data stored in pixel transfer operations; only *format* and *type* matter.

Well, not "only" actually. See, *format* and *type* combine to determine the size of a pixel's worth of data (*format* tells you how many channels are in the data, the ordering of those channels, and whether the data is floating-point or integer; *type* tells you how a channel or pixel value is stored). But to determine how to move from pixel to pixel, row to row, and 2D-image to 2D-image, you need more.

What you need are all of the [`GL_UNPACK_*` state, whose values are set by the `glPixelStore`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Transfer#Pixel_transfer_parameters). `GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` tells you the alignment of each row of pixel data. You need this in order to jump from row to row. There are also other `UNPACK` state, which allows users to select a sub-rectangle to upload from. If you want to interpret what gets uploaded in all cases, you must use `glGetIntegerv` to get *all* of these `UNPACK` parameters and interpret them as the standard specifies.